# Artery (VEINS extension) - LTE and IEEE 802.11p combined

Tags: omnet++, veins, lte, 802.11p

I'm new to Artery, although I have some experience with VEINS.
I've been able to run simulations where all nodes have IEEE 802.11p interfaces, or all nodes have LTE interfaces.

However, I'm having trouble implementing a combined scenario.

Is it possible to run simulations where:

- Some nodes have IEEE 802.11p and other nodes have LTE interfaces?
- Do nodes possess both IEEE 802.11p and LTE interfaces?

If so, how can I achieve it?

Comment: I haven't used Artery, but there's a Veins example on https://github.com/veins/veins_hetvnet which uses both an LTE and a WLAN interface in a host. Maybe it can serve as inspiration for how to do the same thing in Artery.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use the `artery.lte.World` network for this purpose because it features the required LTE modules on top of `artery.inet.World` for WLAN communication.
The `artery.lte.Car` vehicles already come with LTE and WLAN radios. You can control the number of WLAN radios per vehicle via the `numRadios` parameter. Please also have a look at the `traci.MultiTypeModuleMapper` which allows you to use different module types for vehicles, e.g. a mix of `artery.lte.Car` (1 LTE + N WLAN interfaces) and `artery.inet.Car` (0 LTE + N WLAN interfaces).